# Tmp directory deleted, I cannot login to the system

Tags: data-recovery

I missinput a command in a directory(I don't remember what it is.)

> sudo rm -f -r tmp

after that when I restart and log in, I cannot login use the user I have delete the tmp.

However, I can log in with user: root.

Can I resolve the problem?

Comment: The question is not very clear. If you actually did sudo rm -f -t /tmp (instead of just tmp), it could have removed your /tmp directory. If that is the case, you can do sudo mkdir /tmp and sudo chmod 1777 /tmp (assuming /tmp is not a separate filesystem)

Comment: @Jamess I don't think there's another tmp-directory that can cause such problems. I suggest you make that comment an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

The question is not very clear. 
If you actually did sudo rm -f -t /tmp (instead of just tmp) or executed the command while you are at /, it could have actually removed your /tmp directory. /tmp is used for multiple purposes for temporary data storage.

If that is the case, you can do sudo mkdir /tmp and sudo chmod 1777 /tmp (assuming /tmp is not a separate filesystem)  to recreate /tmp directory and to set correct permissions.